# Sending a custom new email from SharePoint 2019

Tags: spfx, 2019

My company has both on premise SharePoint 2019 and SharePoint Online. We just found out that we cannot use SPO for our company intranet due to some security limitations in our current tenant (GCC High). I would like to find a solution that allows me to send a web page as an email from SharePoint 2019, similar to the News Feeds in SPO. SharePoint 2019 only sends a link to the page and not the page content. We would like to use this for company announcements and need to have control over how the email is formatted and include images.

Does anyone have a link to a site that shows an example of how this might be done? I assume this would be done using spfx, but if anyone knows of a good third-party software that does this, that might work as well.